# How to check if string has specific character set in PHP?

Tags: php, string, dom, php-5.3

Suppose I've this string:

```
$string1 = "ABCDEFGMEHULDEF";
```

and I want to run a test

```
if($string1 has MEHUL) {
$variable = true;
}
```

and this SHOULD return true. Any idea how to achieve this in PHP?

Comment: Maybe [strpos](http://uk.php.net/strpos) ?!

Comment: Yes I have an idea. If you would have used Google, you would too…

Comment: I think you mean "character sequence" a [character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charset) is something entirely different.

Comment: I guess strpos locates words, not characters. Since I've got no space in the string, would it work?

Comment: "Would it work?" - try it & let us know.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string1 = "ABCDEFGMEHULDEF";
if (strpos($string1, "MEHUL") != 0) {
  $variable = true;
}
```

RTM ;-) : http://www.php.net/manual/function.strpos.php

Comment: Read The Fuc**ng Manual? :P

Comment: Yes, it helps some times ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = "ABCDEFGMEHULDEF";

if (strpos($str, 'MEHUL') !== FALSE) {
    $variable = true;
}
```

Sorry, didn't see this was already answered.

Comment: Don't worry, better 2 answers than 0 ;)